# Uso del método Ext.getStore()

Tags: javascript, extjs

En el config de mi `Ext.grid.Panel` quiero hacer algo como:

```
store: this.newRecord ? Ext.create('storeId') : Ext.getStore('storeId')
```

¿Es posible y/o deseable?

Entiendo que cuando usamos `Ext.create('storeId')` el Framework crea un nuevo 
store basado en el `modelo`. Pero, si ya tienes ese `store` creado, ¿dónde buscará dicho `store` ?

Me refiero a si el contexto donde buscara ese `store` será **toda** la aplicación, o sólo el contexto del `modulo` donde es llamado, etc.

He buscado más info en la [documentación de Sencha](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#method-getStore) pero sigue sin quedarme claro del todo.